# Can I echo local variable via ssh into remote file?

Tags: perl

I try to write variable in end of file, but write it into STDOUT in local server
some code:

```
$num = <STDIN>
my $cmd = "echo $dep_keys{$num} >> /root/1";
#$ssh->system({stdin_data =>$dep_keys{$num} },"echo >> /root/1");
#$ssh->error die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
#$ssh->system("echo $dep_keys{$num} >> /root/1");
$ssh->system($cmd);
```

I expect that the file will contain new line in the end of file.

Comment: The first problem here is that you're not using strict and warnings. The second problem is that `$num` will usually contain a trailing newline after reading from STDIN, so you should use [chomp](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp) on it.

Comment: The variable is interpolated locally into that string, so it is not a variable anymore on the remote system, and by enabling warnings you will be informed that it is probably just undefined because you didn't chomp `$num`.

Comment: The third problem is that you aren't sanitizing the variable for use in a shell command, which you can use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

defined( my $num = <STDIN> )
   or die("Invalid input");

chomp($num);

defined($dep_keys{$num})
   or die("Invalid input");

my $cmd = shell_quote('printf', '%s\n', $dep_keys{$num}) . ' >>/root/1';
$ssh->system($cmd);
```

Fixes:

- Checks for EOF and other invalid inputs.
- Removes trailing line feed from `$num` (if any).
- Properly convert the text from the hash element into a shell literal.
- Avoids `echo` because `echo` makes impossible to output some strings.